# Selecting highest count of element except when...

Tags: perl, hash, bioinformatics

So i have been working on this perl script that will analyze and count the same letters in different line spaces. I have implemented the count to a hash but am having trouble excluding a " - " character from the output results of this hash. I tried using delete command or next if, but am not getting rid of the - count in the output.

So with this input:

```
@extract = ------------------------------------------------------------------MGG-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And following code:

```
#Count selected amino acids.
my %counter = ();
foreach my $extract(@extract) {
#next if $_ =~ /\-/; #This line code does not function correctly.  
$counter{$_}++;

}


sub largest_value_mem (\%) {
my $counter   = shift;
my ($key, @keys) = keys   %$counter;
my ($big, @vals) = values %$counter;

for (0 .. $#keys) {
    if ($vals[$_] > $big) {
        $big = $vals[$_];
        $key = $keys[$_];
    }
}
$key
```

}

I expect the most common element to be G, same as the output. If there is a tie in the elements, say G = M, if there is a way to display both in  that would be great but not necessary. Any tips on how to delete or remove the '-' is much appreciated. I am slowly learning perl language.

Please let me know if what I am asking is not clear or if more information is needed, thanks again kindly for all the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data doesn't entirely make sense, since it's not actually working perl code.  I'm guessing that it's a string divided into characters.  After that it sounds like you just want to be able to find the highest frequency character, which is essentially just a [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) by descending count.

Therefore the following demonstrates how to count your characters and then sort the results:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '------------------------------------------------------------------MGG-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------';

my @chars = split '', $str;

#Count Characteres
my %count;
$count{$_}++ for @chars;
delete $count{'-'}; # Don't count -

# Sort keys by count descending
my @keys = sort {$count{$b} <=> $count{$a}} keys %count;

for my $key (@keys) {
    print "$key $count{$key}\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
G 2
M 1
```

Comment: I was very close, looks like the for @chars was what was causing me some problems. Thanks Miller for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach my $extract(@extract) {
#next if $_ =~ /\-/
```

*$_* setting is suppressed by *$extract* here.
(In this case, $_ keeps value from above, e.g. routine argument list, previous match, etc.)

Also, you can use character class for better readability:

```
next if $extract=~/[-]/;
```

Comment: Thank you, always trying to optimize the code! Wasn't sure how to write it exactly :D

Comment: I have heard of it but have not used it currently, though it would probably be useful in this context.