# Problems counting letters in perl hash

Tags: perl, hash, count

small problem i'm having for some strange reason. I'm trying to count the number of letters in each string and bring back the highest amount. Below is a sample of the file.

```
@line =

------MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM-M-MMMMMMMM  
------SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS-S-SSSSSDTA  
------TIIIIIIIIIIIIITIIIVVIIIIII-I-IIIIITTT
```

What I tried to do was a hash with a count for each individual element in the line but for some reason it keep bringing me the count of each individual amino acid. I would expect the output to be:

```
M 35
S 32
I 28
```

Comment: `foreach` doesn't iterate over the characters in a string.

Comment: This is pretty much identical to your previous question: [`Selecting highest count of element except when…`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585529/selecting-highest-count-of-element-except-when)

Comment: @Miller I understand it's similar but I was unable to progress and hit a roadblock. Trying to debug the script

Comment: strings in perl are not arrays of characters, they are a basic type.  to get a list of the characters, use `split(//, $string)`

Comment: @ysth I did try that as well but it was behaving oddly, kept giving me the individual characters for some reason.

Comment: no idea what "individual characters" means then; I thought that's what you wanted?

Comment: @ysth What the program was doing was counting each individual character rather than each individual character in the string. Got it running though, thanks for the help ^_^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
foreach my $aa ($string) {
    $counter{$aa}++;
}
```

`($string)` is a list consisting of a single element, so the loop runs just once and is equivalent to `$counter{ $string }++`.

You need to iterate over individual characters in a string. You can do that by splitting the string using an empty pattern as @Miller shows. However, if your string is a large one, you are going to be creating many large lists which may be detrimental to performance. Another alternative is to match each character in turn (you need to decide whether you want to match newlines, spaces etc).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = qw(
    ------MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM-M-MMMMMMMM
    ------SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS-S-SSSSSDTA
    ------TIIIIIIIIIIIIITIIIVVIIIIII-I-IIIIITTT
);

for my $line ( @lines ) {
    my $x = argmax( count_characters($line) );
    print "@$x\n";
}

sub count_characters {
    my $string = shift;
    my %freq;
    while ($string =~ /(.)/g) {
        $freq{ $1 } += 1;
    }
    return \%freq;
}

sub argmax {
    my $freq = shift;
    my ($argmax, $max) = each %$freq;
    while (my ($k, $v) = each %$freq) {
        ($v > $max) and ($argmax, $max) = ($k, $v);
    }
    return [$argmax, $max];
}
```

Output:

```
M 35
S 32
I 28
```

Comment: I am only getting the first element (M 35) as an output. Will keep tinkering with it to get a result. Thank you for your help so far! It was very helpful. Have also gotten L 35 as an answer, seems, from my side, it isn't counting each line, only taking the highest line.

Comment: I can't comment on what your code is doing without seeing the exact code you are running.

Comment: Got it working, was as simple as adding a filehandle. Thanks again Sinan! Very nice script you have there!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `split` the line to iterate over the characters:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %counter;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;

    for my $char (split '', $line) {
        $counter{$char}++;
    }
}

delete $counter{'-'};

while (my ($char, $count) = each %counter) {
    print "$char - $count\n";
}


__DATA__
------MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM-M-MMMMMMMM
------SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS-S-SSSSSDTA
------TIIIIIIIIIIIIITIIIVVIIIIII-I-IIIIITTT
```

Outputs:

```
A - 1
D - 1
M - 35
V - 2
I - 28
T - 6
S - 32
```

Comment: Need the maximum amount of letters per newline, sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for the help.